# UnhandledScheme & cannot read properties of undefined errors using React.JS

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

I am not entirely sure what the best title for something like this is. I am currently working with .Net 6.0 and React 17. I am trying to apply Semantic UI React to this application and am encountering two weird errors when using `npm start` from inside of VS Code and in Powershell/Windows Terminal. The React App compiles but with errors and the resulting localhost page is completely blank (also the React Dev Tools extension can't detect that React is being used on the localhost page).

Below is the first error that is generated by the console. The second one relates to an UnhandledSchemeError and I can post that error message if needed. I can also provide parts of my code as well if requested, though I have no idea where to even start to look for this kind of error.

`ERROR in [entry] [initial] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') during rendering of asset asset/inline|data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') during rendering of asset asset/inline|data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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 at C:\Users\rrobb\Reactivities\client-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\asset\AssetModulesPlugin.js:183:30 at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\rrobb\Reactivities\client-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:12:16) at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (C:\Users\rrobb\Reactivities\client-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14) at Compilation.getRenderManifest (C:\Users\rrobb\Reactivities\client-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:4439:36) at C:\Users\rrobb\Reactivities\client-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:4459:22 at symbolIterator (C:\Users\rrobb\Reactivities\client-app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3482:9) at timesSync (C:\Users\rrobb\Reactivities\client-app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2297:7) at Object.eachLimit (C:\Users\rrobb\Reactivities\client-app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3463:5) at Compilation.createChunkAssets (C:\Users\rrobb\Reactivities\client-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:4452:12) at C:\Users\rrobb\Reactivities\client-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3095:14`

Comment: Quick update : I removed ` 'import semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'; ` from my `Index.tsx` file and took out any other reference to Semantic UI React and it seems to be working with no issue. It seems like my issue is with something in Semantic UI but I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: I downgraded Node from v16 to v14. By doing so, I issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

> This issue is extremely annoying, to workaround it I created
> @semantic-ui-react/css-patch, works with semantic-ui-css &
> semantic-ui-less.

[See Original Post here](https://issueantenna.com/repo/semantic-org/semantic-ui-react/issues/4287#comment-IC_kwDOAj_HUs48l8UE)

*This is TEMPORARY SOLUTION, because developers team didn't fix it yet.
It caused by double semicolon ";;" in the semantic-ui-css files*

**1. Install Patch:**

```
yarn add --dev @semantic-ui-react/css-patch
```

or

```
npm install --dev @semantic-ui-react/css-patch
```

**2. Add it as a postinstall script to your package.json**

```
{
 "scripts": {
   "postinstall": "semantic-ui-css-patch"
 }
}
```

Comment: No, this is not working at all. Did you tested ?